# Error Reading File in Node.js throws weird characters

Tags: node.js

the below code reads file.

```
    var filename = process.cwd() + "\\config\\test1.json";
    var fs = require( 'fs' );
    var contents = fs.readFileSync( filename,"utf8" );
        console.log("contents");
    var rulesObject = JSON.parse( contents );
```

test1.json has the following content

```
textpad
```

Error

```
contents
?textpad

undefined:1
∩╗┐textpad
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ∩╗┐
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readAccessRules (D:\s98799\config\resourceaccess.js:30:26)
    at module.exports.accessRules (D:\s98799\config\resourceaccess.js:6:11)
    at D:\s98799\config\resourceaccess.js:19:4
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\s98799\config\resourceaccess.js:40:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: maybe a dumb question but was the test.json file created and saved in a UTF8 mode editor?

Comment: you are JSON parsing  "textpad" ?!?

Comment: Tried both VS2012 and Notepad with UTF8, no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
  var filename = process.cwd() + "/file.txt";
  var fs = require( 'fs' );
  var contents = fs.readFileSync( filename,"utf8" );
  console.log(contents);
```

this will read the file and log it (change the file.txt to your file)

Comment: you get an error from "var rulesObject = JSON.parse( contents );" because the contents of the file is a plain text, not json.

Comment: for the JSON.parse(contents) to work instead of 'textpad' add this to your test1.json : {"c": "some text"}